# Removing Folders From Gitignore

Tags: git

I installed `Zend2` Skeleton Application to my project. It comes with the `Vendor` folder in the root `gitignore` file.

I removed vendor from the file then

```
git push origin master
```

Then I get

```
Everything up-to-date
```

So I removed the gitignore file all together but I still get the same result. What do I need to have git keep the vendor folder with my project?

Comment: Can you add the output of `git status` to your question?

Comment: You're not supposed to track anything in `vendor` this is what Composer exists for.  `composer update` should be used during development (any broken functionality gets fixed etc) and `composer install` is for production to ONLY pull-in tested and working code.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. but does not change the fact that I need up push it for a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
git rm -r --cached Vendor
git push origin master
```

However is not recommended because Vendors should be managed locally (ie.: composer)

Comment: Yes but when I used composer to install ZFCUser to my project it adds it to Vendor. That being said I am sharing this code with someone and they need to see the work I did with that plugin. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @wuno just upload `composer.json` and `composer.lock`. Then, who will download your branch, should only do `composer install` (and all vendors will be installed in the right folder)

Comment: Yes but how would they see the work I did in the phtml tiles that came with zfcUser? Also your example gives me fatal: pathspec 'vendor' did not match any files. I tried with capital Vendor as you suggested and lowercase because thats what it actually is vendor. either way I get the same fatal error